# What can prototypal approach do that es6 class can't?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, es6-class

Is there anything that can only be achieved with classic/old prototypal approach, yet?

Why I need this: imagine I am writing a subset of JS that is free of old stuff (prototypes instead of classes, var, etc.)

Comment: `class` is just a syntactic sugar for prototypal inheritance so I would not call prototypes "old stuff" :) `if(Math.random() > 0.5){ Ctor.prototype.fn = function() {}}`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Hmm. So there is no option to conditionally set super/parent class?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Oh, I misread your example as `...Ctor.prototype = ...`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Regarding syntactic sugar, I agree. My question is just about that: is that syntactical sugar as capable as the original syntax?

Comment: You  can conditionally set parent class `class C extends (Math.random() > 0.5 ? A : B) {}`. You can't dynamically (say conditionally or in a loop) define members in class body declaration. You'd still need to embrace the fact that there is prototype that actually holds those members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things, including but not limited to:

- When using the `function` notation, you can call the constructor without `new`. The `class` notation forbids this.

  As a side note: where sub-classing would tradionally be done with something like `MyParentClass.call(this)` (which is not allowed when `MyParentClass` was defined with `class`), you would now combine the `class` syntax with the `extends` and `super` keywords.
- `function` declarations can appear after their use, since they are hoisted, `class` declarations are not.
- `function` declarations can be overridden by a new declaration, `class` declarations cannot redefine an earlier declaration
- Prototype methods can be used as constructors when defined in the old style, not when defined using the `class` syntax.
- `function` declarations can be made in "sloppy" mode (not strict), while `class` methods always run in strict mode. As a consequence you cannot use the `caller`, `callee` or `arguments` properties of the methods/constructor in `class` notation. All other consequences of strict mode apply as well of course. It would go too far too list them all here.
- You can assign a new object to an old-style function's `prototype` property (it is writable). With `class` the `prototype` property is not writable (note that this does not mean you cannot *mutate* it).